# Adding a legend to GGPlot Lollipop Chart Based on Colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a lollipop chart with the following code. I am trying to add a legend to the chart, detailing the orange colour as "2020" and the purple colour as "Average". How would I do so?

```
ggplot(LGA_top3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = LGA, xend = LGA, y = 2020, yend = Average)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = LGA, y = 2020), color="orange", size=3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = LGA, y = Average), color="purple", size=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  facet_wrap(~`Offence Category`, ncol=1, scale="free_y") +
  labs(x = "Local Government Area (LGA)", y = "Total")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomment something like this. It is easier if you provide a reproducible example, with your current code there is no way to give you a more accurate answer. Plea use `dput(your_data)` and paste re result here.

```
ggplot(LGA_top3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = LGA, xend = LGA, y = 2020, yend = Average)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = LGA, y = 2020, color = "2020"), size=3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = LGA, y = Average, color = 'Average'), size=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('orange', 'purple')) +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  facet_wrap(~`Offence Category`, ncol=1, scale="free_y") +
  labs(x = "Local Government Area (LGA)", y = "Total")
```

Comment: Thanks Johan, however I get the following error when running this code: Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 0 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Try now, just add `values =`  inside the `scale_color_manual()`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Johan, much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Johan,I have just realised that for some reason, the 2020 value is depicted as a constant, do you know why? The average value is correct.

Comment: Yes. In general when you map a constant to color within aes (), ggplot2 repeat that constant for each point. If you provide a reproducible example of Your data I would hice you a better approach.